# Publishing more than one site on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, domain

I have a setup where `tshepang.github.com` redirects to `tshepang.net`, and have set up my `A record` to point to `204.232.175.78` ([as explained](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages)). It works well.

Now, I want to have a subdomain, so I can have a CNAME record pointing to `movies.tshepang.net`. Since `tshepang.github.com` is already taken, I don't know how to do it, short of creating another GitHub account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42555/5200), for each site that would end up accessible as a sub-domain:

- I need to create a separate GitHub repository
- Ensure to have the desired site url in the CNAME
- `git push` the site onto `gh-pages` branch

To make those sites accessible from the internet, my settings look like this:

[image]

Now, `movies.tshepang.net` takes me to one site, `demo-icbu.tshepang.net` takes me to another, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, how is this different from my answer? I am referring to having domains like foo.github.io **AND** bar.github.io all under a single account. You can have unlimited sub-domains if you use your own domain name and add the relevant CNAMES.

Comment: Using the web interface, I could not get CNAMEs to work. By *add relevant CNAMES*, do you mean the text files required by GitHub? Also, I don't understand what you mean by foo and bar... I thought one can only have one of either (in my case `tshepang.github.io`).

Comment: Is there maybe a video tutorial explaining this. Does it work for multiple sites as opposed to subdomains and multiple sites that might include a subdomain too? site.com, site2.com, sub.site2.com etc etc?

Comment: I see only master branch and no gh-pages branch is present

Answer (score 35):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple GitHub Pages sites within one account. Create another GitHub repository and push your site files to the `gh-pages` branch. This would result in the site being hosted at `tshepang.github.io/<repo-name>`.

Now, push another file "CNAME" to the same repository and branch and fill it with `movies.tshepang.net`. Log in to your DNS host and add the CNAME to point to "tshepang.github.io" (just like the original site).

This would allow you to have seemingly two different sites on different domains. This would not work for having two or more sub-domains within github.io itself.

Comment: Why the limitation, *...would not work for having two or more sub-domains within github.com itself*? Is there a reference somewhere?

Comment: I can't really find anything that explains it, I only found out through experience. You can try creating another repository with another sub-domain and see if it works.

Comment: I've tried with 9 sub-domains, and it works. It takes a while though... several minutes for each sub-domain.

Comment: @Tshepang Wow, you just created the respective repositories and it all works?

Comment: yes sir, indeed it does

Comment: Old answer, but: I am trying this and it seems to work fine with http. When I try to enable "enforce HTTPS" in the repo settings, I get an error (after reloading) that " Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server", which is a bit odd. Maybe it goes away after a while...

Comment: Yep, indeed. Still works fine, and even works with https! :) Thanks a lot @Hydra!

Comment: what is the gh-pages branch? I only have a master branch...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is answered for some time already, but you can even have multiple pages within the same repository. See my answer on Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879114/1297835